# Why do I not have permissions to run this method?

Tags: mac, permissions, debug, ruby

I'm using a Ruby gem called [IMGKit](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit) and when I use the gem's `to_img` method in the console I get this error:

```
IMGKit::CommandFailedError: Command failed: /rubyprograms/search --format jpg http://google.com -: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:67:in `exec': Permission denied - /rubyprograms/search (Errno::EACCES)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:67:in `popen3'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:53:in `fork'
```

I have no clue what's going on.

This is the to_img method:

```
def to_img(format = nil)
  append_stylesheets
  set_format(format)

  result = nil
  stderr_output = nil
  Open3.popen3(*command) do |stdin,stdout,stderr|
    stdin << (@source.to_s) if @source.html?
    stdin.close
    result = stdout.gets(nil)
    result.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT") if result.respond_to? :force_encoding
    stderr_output = stderr.readlines.join
    stdout.close
    stderr.close
  end
  raise CommandFailedError.new(command.join(' '), stderr_output)  unless result
  return result
end
```

For some reason it seems I do not have access to this method on Mac OSX. What are some things I should do to find out what the problem is and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Re-read the error message:

> Command failed: /rubyprograms/search --format jpg http://google.com -: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/**open3.rb:67:in `exec': Permission denied - /rubyprograms/search (Errno::EACCES)**

The "Permission denied" error is returned from `kernel.exec()` ← `Open3.popen3()` when trying to execute command `/rubyprograms/search`. Make sure that file has execute permission (`chmod +x`), try running it from Terminal.